# Mongo create request for embedded subfields

Tags: mongodb

I'm new to mongo and need help finding db entries created at requested time. In my example there are a lot of embedded fields, and I do not understand syntaxis for request:

```
{
  "_id": "54e1a045e4b03f5930293da6",
  "_version": 31867,
  "_transId": "4ae4d0e6-d3df-4a24-9621-1cdb7f12362f-10489329",
  "accountBalances": {
    "BALANCE": {
      "thresholds": {

      },
      "quotas": "ROLLOVER_QUOTA": {
        "thresholds": {

        },
        "quotaCode": "ROLLOVER_QUOTA",
        "credits": {
          "_1HVa0dJoEeSUwbM1-xYKvg": {
            "startDate": ISODate("2015-03-24T21:00:00Z"),
            "creditAmount": "547194099151",
            "endDate": ISODate("2020-03-24T21:00:00Z"),
            "started": true,
            "debits": {
              "consolidated": {
                "creationDate": ISODate("2015-04-17T18:00:01.469Z"),
                "debitAmount": "547194090291",
                "debitId": "consolidated"
              }
            },
            "creditId": "_1HVa0dJoEeSUwbM1-xYKvg"
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

I need to search for entries which have debit creation date `$gte:ISODate("2015-03-16T00:00:00.000Z"), $lte:ISODate("2015-03-16T04:00:00.000Z"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **[dot notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation)** to access the fields of an embedded document:

```
db.collection.find(
    {
        "accountBalances.BALANCE.quotas.ROLLOVER_QUOTA.credits._1HVa0dJoEeSUwbM1-xYKvg.debits.creationDate": {
             "$gte": ISODate("2015-03-16T00:00:00.000Z"), 
             "$lte": ISODate("2015-03-16T04:00:00.000Z")
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Hello, I tried this but it did not work. I think that is because I have a credit name, as in 
     'code'credits": {
          "_1HVa0dJoEeSUwbM1-xYKvg": {
            "startDate":

Is there a way to use "any: expression for this field ?

Comment: @DzmitryCharadnichenka Oh, that's a bad schema design. It's going to be pretty difficult to update embedded documents with dynamic keys.